# how to get random element of array which is not null?

Tags: javascript

Let's say i haven an array of `let arr = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]` containing 9 items.

And i have 9 `<button data-index>` with each having an `data-index=0` to `data-index=9`

If i click a button, let's say `<button data-index=4>`, then we assign `'Cookie'` to the corresponding index of arr: `arr[4] = 'Cookie'`

arr becomes `[null, null, null, null, 'Cookie', null, null, null, null]`

How can i select a random element/index of `arr` which is `null` without it selecting `arr[4]` since it already contains `Cookie`?.

It's for the AI move of a tic-tac-toe game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ES6 solution with filter:

```js
var arr = [null, null, null, null, 'Cookie', null, null, null, null];

var indexes = Array.from(Array(arr.length).keys());
var availableIndexes = indexes.filter((index) => arr[index] == null);
var selectedIndex = availableIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random()* availableIndexes.length)];

console.log(availableIndexes);
console.log(selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a fisher-yates shuffle to get a random order of the indices of the array and then pick them one by one.

Idea is to set the random index to the buttons at the start. And not compute the random index on click.

Answer (score 2):

```
var randomIndex = 0;
while ( arr[randomIndex] != null ) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * (arr.length - 1) );
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
var arr = [null, null, null, null, 'Cookie', null, null, null, null];
var indexes = [];
for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == null)
        indexes.push(i);
}
var index = indexes[parseInt(Math.random() * (indexes.length - 1))];

alert(index);
```